# How does new line escaping need to formated to get message to display correctly

Tags: php, line-breaks

I have the following saved to my `$msg` variable. On display my goal was to get it to print formatted correctly with new lines. I am not sure what I could do differently. On a side note I could be going about creating the message all wrong.

```
$msg ="Hey ".$row['emailName']."\rYou recently signed up to receive email updates from us, and we wanted to verify your email address.\nIf you signed  up to receive updates please press the confirmation link below:\nwww.domain.com/validateemail?email=".$row['emailAddress']."&emailID=".$row['emailID']."&emailed=1\nThe request came from".$row['signupIP']."\nIf you did not make this request, you can ignore this email\n \r Thanks,\rKathleen Williams\rHead Trainer";
```

The issue is that it isn't displaying line breaks.

Comment: `\r` is not a new line; `\n` is the new line character. `www.domain.com/validateemail...` is not an URL. An URL starts with a protocol (`http://`, `https://` etc). Without it, the email client doesn't detect it as an URL and doesn't create a link from it.

Comment: @axiac `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` are the EOL symbols, just they are from the different OS (-;

Comment: @Neodan [The OSes that use `\r` as EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) are either obscure (niche products) or defunct for years. The most known of them is the ["Classic" Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS) that was replaced by [Mac OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_10.0) (aka "OS X", aka [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)) 15 years ago. macOS and the myriad of Linux distributions use `\n` as EOL, Windows uses `\r\n` as EOL but none of them recognizes a single `\r` as EOL.

Comment: @axiac you are wrong, `\r` (CR) still is supported and recognized as EOL. Yes it is very old and unpopular (rarely used) EOL, but it is EOL. Just try it on the text editors, Firefox, ect. and you will see that \r still works.

Comment: @Neodan *"Just try it on the text editors"* -- I tried it in Notepad and `vi` (the default text editors that come with Windows and Linux). They don't recognize `\r` as an end of line. The same for most of the tools that come with Linux (`sed`, `wc`, `grep`, `head`, `tail` etc). I don't have a macOS at hand (I'll check on it later today) but I doubt the same tools on macOS recognize `\r` as an end of line character. We're in 2017 and `\r` as EOL is a fairy tale from a distant past.

Comment: @axiac for me `\r` works on: nano, gedit, mousepad, Atom, PHPStorm. Yes `\r` is ancient EOL, but still... it is EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code:

- `\r` is not a new line; `\n` is the new line character.
- `www.domain.com/validateemail?...` is not an URL. An URL starts with a protocol (`http://`, `https://` etc). Without it, the email client doesn't detect it as an URL and doesn't create a link from it.

There are several ways to write the code to be easy to read and modify. For example, you can use the [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for strings. It allows you to write the text on multiple lines without worrying how to write newline characters. Also, PHP [parses it for variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) and escape sequences the same way it does with [double quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

```
// The text starting after the line `<<< END` and ending before 
// the marker provided after `<<<` is a string.
// It is stored into the $msg variable.
$textBody = <<< END_TEXT
Hey {$row['emailName']}
You recently signed up to receive email updates from us, and we wanted to verify your email address.
If you signed  up to receive updates please press the confirmation link below:

    http://www.example.com/validateemail?email={$row['emailAddress']}&emailID={$row['emailID']}&emailed=1

The request came from {$row['signupIP']}.
If you did not make this request, you can ignore this email.

Thanks,
Kathleen Williams
Head Trainer

END_TEXT;
```

If you want to send HTML email you can use the same technique to generate the email body but don't forget that HTML doesn't care about the newlines in the source code. Wrap the text in `<p>` HTML elements to produce paragraphs and use the `<br>` HTML element to force a new line inside a paragraph.

The code could be like this:

```
$htmlBody = <<< END_HTML
<p>Hey {$row['emailName']}</p>
<p>You recently signed up to receive email updates from us,
and we wanted to verify your email address.<br>
If you signed  up to receive updates please press this 
<a href="http://www.example.com/validateemail?email={$row['emailAddress']}&amp;emailID={$row['emailID']}&amp;emailed=1">confirmation link</a>.</p>

<p>The request came from {$row['signupIP']}.<br>
If you did not make this request, you can ignore this email.</p>

<p>Thanks,<br>
Kathleen Williams<br>
Head Trainer</p>

END_HTML;
```

Comment: Yes \r is ancient EOL, but still... it is EOL. Take a look into `Description` section  of http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

Different OS use the different symbols for end of line (EOL):

- `\r\n` - CRLF (Windows)
- `\n`   - LF (Unix and OS X)
- `\r` - CR (Mac)

If you printing out this message in HTML, then you must change the EOL symbol into `<br>` tag, because EOL symbols are ignored.

You can use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for converting.